# Why Does Not My File Explorer See A Mounted Folder?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, root-access, 4.4-kitkat, mount, command-line

Why can't i see a mounted folder into my file explorer (checked ES file explorer and RootBrowser) , but i can see it from a terminal?

I'm mounting a folder (/mnt/sdcard/Source) into other folder (/mnt/sdcard/Destination) with the next command (requieres Root permissions):

```
mount -o bind /mnt/sdcard/Source /mnt/sdcard/Destination
```

If i check with the ls command, i can see the files, but not on my explorer.

I'm testing it on a Moto G running Android 4.4.2 (Kitkat), but the same command works fine on Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean).

Comment: Just wondering is your file explorer kit-kat compliant - there was permission changes made to kit-kat regarding SDCard storage.

Comment: I guess they changed permissions to sdcard, about my file explorer, i'm using ES file explorer and RootBrowser, and none of them show me the files. I also tried chmod -R 777 (Read, Write, execute) in both "Source" and "Destination". But nothing happens.

Comment: I was not actually referring to permissions as in un*x permissions, rather referring to the API changes made regarding accessing SDCard storage..

Comment: I get it, and yeah, im pretty sure they made something about storage because i can use my stored files on the phone while it's connected to usb on storage mode.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like here's the answer and solution: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2718760 .
Quoting biopsin.

> Since Android 4.2 and the intro of multiusers there is a problem with bind folders across sdcards, making any attempt on mount bind folders as root would result in visible to root only.
>   Solution is to fool Android with temporary hijack debuggerd to create the mount binds for us. Thanks Chainfire for this workaround!
>   * Download both files and rename without .txt
>   * edit debuggerd.mnt to suit your needs (using any other dir then /emulated/legacy/ will result in read only if browsing folders from sdcard0)
>   * move debuggerd.mnt to /system/bin
>   * move mount.sh to any place with execute permissions
>   * execute mount.sh with any preferred method.
>     cheers!

Content of "debuggerd.mnt.txt" below.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# Mount sd hack
mount -o bind /storage/sdcard1/Download /storage/emulated/legacy/Download
mount -o bind /storage/sdcard1/Ebooks /storage/emulated/legacy/eBooks
mount -o bind /storage/sdcard1/Pictures /storage/emulated/legacy/DCIM
mount -o bind /storage/sdcard1/Pictures /storage/emulated/legacy/Pictures
```

And below content of "mount.sh.txt".

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# Mount hack
mount -o remount,rw /system
stop debuggerd
mv /system/bin/debuggerd /system/bin/debuggerd.bak
mv /system/bin/debuggerd.mnt /system/bin/debuggerd
start debuggerd
sleep 2
stop debuggerd
mv /system/bin/debuggerd /system/bin/debuggerd.mnt
mv /system/bin/debuggerd.bak /system/bin/debuggerd
start debuggerd
mount -o remount,ro /system
echo "Mount hack enabled"
```